# NSScrollView detect scroll position

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview

How can i detect scroll of position when the scroll at bottom?

```
[[_scrollView contentView] setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(boundsDidChangeNotification:)
                                             name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification
                                           object:[_scrollView contentView]];





- (void) boundsDidChangeNotification: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSPoint currentScrollPosition = [[_scrollView contentView] bounds].origin;
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the `UIScrollViewDelegate`? (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html)

Comment: I can not find information in document... it's OS X code. not iOS

Comment: Have you checked if the notification is firing?

Comment: how to calculate the scroll position?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the `cocoa` tag.

Answer (score 15):

**Update**:
My original answer was plain wrong.
Thanks to JWWalker and Wil Shipley for making me aware of that via comments.

Here's a hopefully more helpful answer for people coming here via search:
Unlike `UIScrollView`, `NSScrollView` does not provide a delegate method to inform you when a view was scrolled to top/bottom.
To detect those situations, you have to enable `boundsDidChange` notifications and subscribe to them.

When receiving a bounds update, you can check if the `y` coordinate of the clip view bounds is `0` (= bottom), or if the top edge of the clip view bounds aligns with the document view (= top).

```
private func configureScrollView() {
        self.scrollView.contentView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications = true
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(contentViewDidChangeBounds), name: NSView.boundsDidChangeNotification, object: self.scrollView.contentView)
    }

@objc
func contentViewDidChangeBounds(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let documentView = scrollView.documentView else { return }

    let clipView = scrollView.contentView
    if clipView.bounds.origin.y == 0 {
        print("bottom")
    } else if clipView.bounds.origin.y + clipView.bounds.height == documentView.bounds.height {
        print("top")
    }
}
```

For scroll views that use elastic scrolling, the updates come with a short delay because the clip view seems to defer the bounds change notifications until the scroll bounce has finished.

<strike>You can use the visible rect of your `NSScrollView`'s contentView instead of the bounds:</strike>

```
- (void)boundsDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSRect visibleRect = [[_scrollView contentView] documentVisibleRect];
    NSLog(@"Visible rect:%@", NSStringFromRect(visibleRect));
    NSPoint currentScrollPosition = visibleRect.origin;
}
```

The content view bounds don't change during scrolling, so in your original code, the bounds.origin probably always returns 0/0.

Comment: This should be the better answer IMO.

Comment: The origin of the content view does change during scrolling.  Maybe you were thinking of the document view.

Comment: The `contentView`’s (aka `NSClipView`’s) origin absolutely changes during scrolling, that is how scrolling works. The `visibleRect` does NOT change.

Comment: it works great. but when I run   print("bottom") when I scroll to top and vice versa

Answer (score 7):

```
if (_scrollView.verticalScroller.floatValue > 0.9)
{
    // bottom
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to detect after scroll ended. @thomas's answer is detect when view is scrolling

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(scrollViewDidScroll),
                name:NSScrollView.didLiveScrollNotification,
                object: scrollView
            )



  @objc func scrollViewDidScroll (notification: NSNotification) {

        guard let documentView = scrollView.documentView else { return }

        let clipView = scrollView.contentView
        if clipView.bounds.origin.y == 0 {
            print("top")

        } else if clipView.bounds.origin.y + clipView.bounds.height == documentView.bounds.height {

            print("bottom")

}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the actual language OP requested:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSView* objectToTrack = self.tableView.enclosingScrollView.contentView;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(didObserveScrolling:)
                                                 name: NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification
                                               object: objectToTrack];
}

- (void) didObserveScrolling: (id) sender
{
    self.needsDisplay = YES;
    //or do whatever you need to in response for the content scrolling

}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];
}
```

I use this in a custom view that acts as a NSTableView footer to display column averages.