# How to keep track of where a NSTableView is scrolled to?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I want to set a variable to the scroll position of a NSTableView. So every time the user scrolls, the variable changes to where the NSTableView is scrolled to. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a user has scrolled to the end of an NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959544/how-to-determine-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-end-of-an-nstableview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSScrollView detect scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127183/nsscrollview-detect-scroll-position)